# Can I implement passport js into my back-end express app

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node,so this maybe be a silly question but I would like to know if it is possible to implement the api passport js into my back-end express app ?

Answer (score 1):

Yup: here's a tutorial on it: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-authentication-passport-js/

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good tutorial where I was able to get passport js to work on the back-end
https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens